# How to convert geospatial data with a custom SRS into ESRI Shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, convert, epsg

I want to convert geospatial data stored in a .csv file into GeoJSON or ESRI Shapefiles. The problem is that the coordinate reference system is not in the database of EPSG codes. The originator however provides a .prj file with the relevant information.

```
// ETRS89_UTM_Zone_33_BB_6stellig.prj
PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM_Zone33_6",
  GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",
    DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
  ],
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15.0],
  PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
  UNIT["Meter",1.0]
]
```

Source: [Landesvermessung und Geobasisinformationen Brandenburg](http://www.geobasis-bb.de/LGB1/service/etrs89.htm)

Comment: Is at least the geodetic datum matching on any one you can find on http://spatialreference.org/ ? If you have to do a geodetic datum transformation, you will need transformation parameters, which you normally can't get by yourself except you are an mathematics and/or geodetic genius. Perhaps you can post the content of the prj file here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ogr2ogr and have a valid .prj file, you don't need a matching EPSG Code.

CSV itself does not have CRS information, so you have to **apply** the definition with ogr2ogr.

Your input file `points.csv` should look like this

> ```
> id,x,y
> 0,455795.63291,5767308.43056
> 1,448404.098752,5790679.95123
> 2,437594.358317,5777140.87242
> ```

You need a vrt file `points.vrt` to tell ogr2ogr which columns contain the geometry information:

> ```
> <OGRVRTDataSource>
>     <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
>         <SrcDataSource>points.csv</SrcDataSource>
>         <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
>         <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
>     </OGRVRTLayer>
> </OGRVRTDataSource>
> ```

The command should be:

```
ogr2ogr -a_srs ETRS89_UTM_Zone33_6stellig.prj points.shp points.vrt
```

This will definitely work for shapefiles. For Geojson, the CRS must be linked as described in http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linked-crs

Alternatively, you can use this vrt:

> ```
> <OGRVRTDataSource>
>     <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
>         <SrcDataSource>points.csv</SrcDataSource>
>         <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
>       <LayerSRS>ETRS89_UTM_Zone33_6stellig.prj </LayerSRS>
>         <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
>     </OGRVRTLayer>
> </OGRVRTDataSource>
> ```

and a commandline without a_srs:

```
ogr2ogr points.shp points.vrt
```

---

But to be honest, I see no differences in parameters to the standard EPSG:25833:

```
PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM_zone_33N",
  GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",
    DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",
    SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: It generates a .dbf file only. Can you tell what the ogr2ogr driver expects as the correct column names for longitude and latitude values? I wonder if I can combine the .prj (custom EPSG-code) with a .vrt definition?

Comment: See my extended answer. I usually do this in QGIS, adding a delimited text file, then saving as a shapefile. You get an overview of the points as well.

Comment: Thank you. It finally worked with `ETRS89_UTM_Zone33_7stellig.prj`. My .vrt file contained `<LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>` which is a problem when I specify the SRS via the `.prj` file, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left out that line. But   `<LayerSRS>ETRS89.prj</LayerSRS>` would work too.

Comment: You mean `<LayerSRS>ETRS89_UTM_Zone33_6stellig.prj</LayerSRS>` for the example?

Comment: Yes, and no a_srs in the ogr2ogr command line needed.

Comment: Understood. It would be `ogr2ogr points.shp point.vrt` then. Feel free to add the alternative to your answer.